# Java output XML file and CDATA

Tags: java, xml

I am having a problem with the javax.xml.transform.Transformer class and its setOutputProperty method. I'm trying to get a XML output

```
   <name>
  <text>XXXXXXXXXX</text>
</name>
<questiontext format="html">
  <text><![CDATA[YYYYYYYYYYY]]></text>
</questiontext>
```

But using the:

```
        Transformer trans = transfac.newTransformer();
    trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.CDATA_SECTION_ELEMENTS, "text");
```

causes for the both of text nodes to be embedded by CDATA tags like so:

```
    <name>
  <text><![CDATA[XXXXXXXXXX]]></text>
</name>
<questiontext format="html">
  <text><![CDATA[YYYYYYYYYYY]]></text>
</questiontext>
```

So i guess i need a way to specify the parent of the text element but i haven't found a way to do so and the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/OutputKeys.html#CDATA_SECTION_ELEMENTS) don't specify which notation is used. Also i am not in a position to change the output XML format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't - the `OutputKeys.CDATA_SECTION_ELEMENTS` output property corresponds to the XSLT `cdata-section-elements` attribute of `<xsl:output>`, and that only allows you to define the elements in terms of QNames, not match expressions.

But it shouldn't matter since `<foo>text</foo>` and `<foo><![CDATA[text]]></foo>` are identical as far as an XML parser is concerned.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't know what parser will be used on my XML later on but I hope this extra CDATA doesn't cause any problems which it shouldn't. I even tried to pass a String with CDATA tag included but then the Transformer had problems parsing the "<" and ">" characters.

Comment: `<foo>text</foo>` and `<foo><![CDATA[text]]></foo>` are not identical at all. Consider `"text"` to contain XML characters such as `"t<>/./?><<<>M"`. In that case, wrapping into CDATA will be your only option, and will definelty matter as far as an XML parser is concerned.